# Citing articles in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to cite another paper (`keyB`) inside a `note` of `keyC`, marking `keyC` as "superseded" by `keyB`.

When I do so, biblatex fails to respect the `maxcitenames` parameter. How do I get "Superseded by One et al. (2015b)" instead of the full author list? Note that I would like to keep the current global setting of `maxbibnames`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@Inproceedings{keyA,
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
    title={titleA},
    booktitle={bookA},
    year=2015,
}
@inproceedings{keyB,
  Title = {titleB},
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
  booktitle={bookB},
  year=2015,
}

@Inbook{keyC,
  Title = {titleC},
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
  booktitle={bookC},
  year=2016,
  % The following /should/ print ``One et al.'', but prints all four authors.
  note = {Superseded by \citet{keyB}}
}
\end{filecontents} 


\usepackage[natbib,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,style=authoryear,
    mincitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document}
\citet{keyA}

\citet{keyB}

\citet{keyC}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bibliography biblatex uses the value of maxbibnames. But you can restore the cite value before the cite command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\restoremaxcitenames{\let\blx@maxbibnames\blx@maxcitenames}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Inproceedings{keyA,
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
    title={titleA},
    booktitle={bookA},
    year=2015,
}
@inproceedings{keyB,
  Title = {titleB},
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
  booktitle={bookB},
  year=2015,
}

@Inbook{keyC,
  Title = {titleC},
  author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four},
  booktitle={bookC},
  year=2016,
  % The following /should/ print ``One et al.'', but prints all four authors.
  note = {Superseded by {\restoremaxcitenames\citet{keyB}}},
  related={keyB},
  relatedstring={Superseded by}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[natbib,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,style=authoryear,
    mincitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\citet{keyA}

\citet{keyB}

\citet{keyC}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good! Does that permanently change the value, or just for the current citet?

Comment: Imho this should be in a group, but to be sure I added some braces.

Comment: @hannes If you use the `\cite` commands regularly inside `note` fields you could think about adding the `\restoremaxcitenames` to the field format, so you don't have to call it manually every time.

Comment: @moewe thanks! For reference, this is the format I use now:
`\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\restoremaxcitenames #1\isdot}`